# LinkedQueue implementation used to store flights

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a LinkedQueue Structure in c++ to store the data of some flights.

So, first of all I have to read a csv file, what provides the data to store. 
The LinkedQueue must work this way: the atributes of each Flight has to be stored using the Flight class, and then the LinkedQueue must have a specific nodes called FlightNode to finally store flights. 
My code isn't compiling because i can't implement the getNext() function in a correct way.

I'm giving my code below with the implementation of each class. If you guys can make any suggestion it will be very helpfull.

Thank you a lot!!

This is my header class for Flight.h:

```
class Flight { 
public:
    Flight();
    virtual ~Flight();
    string getID();
    void setID(string new_id);
    string getOrigen();
    void setOrigen(string new_origen);
    string getDesti();
    void setDesti(string new_desti);
    string getHora();
    void setHora(string new_hora);

private:
    string id;
    string origen;
    string desti;
    string hora_sortida;

};
```

Flight.cpp:

```
Flight::Flight() {

}

Flight::~Flight() {
}

string Flight::getID(){
    return id;
}

string Flight::getOrigen(){
    return origen;
}

string Flight::getDesti(){
    return desti;
}

string Flight::getHora(){
    return hora_sortida;
}

void Flight::setID(string new_id){
    id = new_id;
}

void Flight::setOrigen(string new_origen){
    origen = new_origen;
}

void Flight::setDesti(string new_desti){
    desti = new_desti;
}

void Flight::setHora(string new_hora){
    hora_sortida = new_hora;
}
```

FlightNode.h:

```
class FlightNode {
public:
    FlightNode(Flight& f);
    FlightNode(const FlightNode& orig);
    virtual ~FlightNode();
    FlightNode* getNext();
    void setNext(FlightNode* n);
    Flight& getElement();
private:
    Flight* _element;
    FlightNode* _next;

};
```

FlightNode.cpp:

```
FlightNode::FlightNode(Flight& f) {
    this->_element = &f;
    this->_next = nullptr;
}

FlightNode::FlightNode(const FlightNode& orig) {
}

FlightNode::~FlightNode() {
}
FlightNode* FlightNode::getNext(){
    return this->_next;
}

void FlightNode::setNext(FlightNode* n){
    this->_next = n; 
}

Flight& FlightNode::getElement(){
    //Don't know how to implement this one, because I declared _element as a pointer but what I need here is to return a reference. 
}
```

main.cpp:

```
    string id;
    string origen;
    string desti;
    string hora;

            fstream fin;
            fin.open("flights.csv", ios::in);

            string line, word;
            string id, origen, desti, hora;

            while (getline(fin, line)) {
                stringstream in(line);
                Flight* new_flight = new Flight;
                for (int i = 0; getline(in, word, ','); ++i) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            new_flight->setID(word);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            new_flight->setOrigen(word);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            new_flight->setDesti(word);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            new_flight->setHora(word);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                cout << "id:" << new_flight->getID() << "  origen:" << new_flight->getOrigen() << "  desti: " << new_flight->getDesti() << endl;
                queue.enqueue(*new_flight);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return the reference behind the pointer:

```
return *_element;
```

However, if you plan to do so please ensure that the pointer is not null at the time of the above dereference.

Comment: I've already tried, but then i'm getting the following error: LinkedQueue.cpp:38:39: error: binding ‘const Flight’ to reference of type ‘Flight&’ discards qualifiers
     FlightNode* tmp = new FlightNode(f);
                                       ^
In file included from LinkedQueue.h:13:0,
                 from LinkedQueue.cpp:14:
FlightNode.h:22:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘FlightNode::FlightNode(Flight&)’
     FlightNode(Flight& f);

Comment: Are you calling the function on a `const` object?

Comment: Nope ‍♀️ Really lost on this

Comment: Hm, the signature says that this happens in the copy-constructor, whose parameter signature is `const&`. Are you calling it in there?